How to determine if one IPv4 address is visible from another?
I am learning TCP/IP networking, and am having a bit of trouble putting it all together into a working understanding. I am wondering how one can determine whether a packet from one host can reach another, based on network topology and IP addresses.
For example, can 10.0.0.4 "see" 192.168.0.100? What determines which subnet a machine is on?
If I have one router at 10.0.0.1, and another at 10.0.0.2, how can hosts connected to 10.0.0.1 talk to hosts on 10.0.0.2?

Are you asking about subnetting (and broadcast domains) or routing? Because with routing it’s basically “anything goes”.

I suppose I may be getting my terms mixed up. If I'm not mistaken, NAT forwarding can be used to route traffic from one segment of the network to another, no? But how can it be determined if one subnet can see another without NAT?

No, routing can be used to route traffic from one segment to another. NAT only comes into play as a workaround when routing cannot be set up in one direction, or similar issues. (It's basically duct tape for routing.)

10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 is on the same subnet. Do you know how to determine a subnet? It’s an essential knowledge if your learning networking

@TomasGray based on the answers, it's pretty clear that this question is very ambiguous. First, the definition of "see" is not technical. Could you add some details on what you mean by "see". Additionally, the question needs some background on the network topology in your setup. Every answer has made assumptions about the network topology here. Also, checkout networkengineering.stackexchange.com. The meta forum out there would be a great place to get help to refine your question.

A device's IP address, together with its subnet mask, determines what subnet it is on.
The subnet mask, in binary, has binary 1's for all the bits "on the left" (most significant) that represent the network number, and binary 0's for all the bits "on the right" (least significant) that represent this device's host number within its subnet. By doing a bitwise "AND" operation of the IP address and subnet mask, you end up with the subnet number.
When a host needs to send a packet to another IP address, it sees if the destination IP address is on the same subnet. If it is, the host checks via ARP (I'm assuming Ethernet or an Ethernet-like LAN technology here) to find the MAC address of the target machine to so it can address the frame directly to the other host at the Ethernet layer. If the destination address is NOT on the same subnet, then the host checks via ARP for the MAC address of its default gateway, and addresses just the Ethernet frame to the MAC address of the default gateway (the IP-layer destination address is still that of the ultimate designation host), so that the gateway receives the packet and can take responsibility for forwarding it along the correct next hop of the best route toward the destination host.
For this reason, your default gateway must be on the same subnet as your IP address.
So the host at 10.0.0.4 can reach the host at 192.168.0.100 if there is one or more routers providing a route between those two subnets.


I am learning TCP/IP networking, and am having a bit of trouble putting it all together into a working understanding. I am wondering how one can determine whether a packet from one host can reach another, based on network topology and IP addresses.

More-or-less anything can be made reachable (either in the proper way or creatively), but you cannot determine that purely from IP addresses, or even looking at a network map.
When looking at a diagram of a single network, it's a safe default to assume that everything is routed and every subnet is reachable from any other subnet unless indicated otherwise, since that's the real goal of networking.
In practice, though, you need to know the configuration of all routers involved – what IP address/netmask is each interface configured with? do the routers have routes every step along the way? (or if not, are workarounds like NAT or proxy-ARP being applied to compensate?) And do they have routes back from B to A? (it is often forgotten that routes are necessary in both directions; replies do not automatically know their way back)
You always start with your local network segment. Your "netmask" or "subnet mask" or "prefix length" is what tells the OS whether a given address is in the same segment as you. (It's impossible to tell from just the addresses alone – e.g. 192.168.2.9 and 192.168.3.15 may be in the same /16, or in two different /24's – but straightforward to calculate it when given the netmask.)
Generally, a host would be local to one subnet, and would have one route through one gateway for everything else. A router, on the other hand, would be local to at least two subnets (or three, or four) and would have potentially a lot of routes for many networks through various other gateways. (Though it's not a strict division; hosts can have routes as well, it's merely not their job usually.)
This is assuming that configuration is done correctly and 1:1 reflects the actual topology. In reality IP is much more flexible and all kinds of tricks can be used, e.g. multiple IP subnets coexisting on the same segment (where hosts may or may not know about the other subnets being directly reachable), or a single subnet spread across two segments (with proxy-ARP to "glue" it back), and so on.

For example, can 10.0.0.4 "see" 192.168.0.100?

It really depends on what you mean by 'see'. Send a packet? Send and receive a packet? Send a broadcast packet? (Sometimes people use that term to mean the host being pingable, and sometimes they mean the host literally showing up in the sort of "Nearby devices" list that Windows has... and those two have very different requirements.)
In general, it is absolutely possible that 10.0.0.4 would be able to send a packet to 192.168.0.100 – it doesn't really matter how the networks are numbered, as long as routers have the necessary routes – but the routers also might not have routes (or they might have deliberate filters/firewalls), so it's impossible to guarantee an answer based on addresses alone.

What determines which subnet a machine is on?

The network administrator, the routers' configuration, and the physical topology.
Generally, on a router, each port would be its own interface (a separate segment) configured for a separate IP subnet, and hosts connected to that interface are connected to that subnet. Your home router has a 'LAN' interface configured for 192.168.1.1/24 (divided into four ports via Ethernet switch, but still only one interface logically), so the hosts connected to the same segment also belong to the same 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

If I have one router at 10.0.0.1, and another at 10.0.0.2, how can hosts connected to 10.0.0.1 talk to hosts on 10.0.0.2?

They consult their routing table, send packets towards the appropriate router, that router consults its routing table, sends packets towards the next router, etc.
Though this really depends on what topology you had in mind. There is one way to build a two-router network as described (in which 10.0.0.x is the interconnection between the routers) but I'm not sure if that's what you were thinking of.
